# Can I access ListView Item data and underlying database data from a ListView popup menu?

Tags: android, listview

- I have an activity which displays a Listview.
- The Listview uses a CursorAdapter to show data read from a SQLite database.
- I have implemented a button which appears on each ListView item.
- Clicking the button calls a 'onClickListener' which displays a popup menu (by inflating 'PopupMenu').
- I need to access data from the ListView Item in the onMenuItemClick handler in order to continue processing.

Is there any way I can do this?

I asked a much longer version of this question containing code, but it didn't get any response so I thought it might be too long and I've now deleted it.

My code showed that I have tried implementing the click handlers in two ways:-

- via XML android:onClick, so the click handlers appear in the Activity code
- and dynamically, so the click handlers appear in the CursorAdapter code.

I can't find a way to access the List Item data in either. There seems to be no way of getting to it via the View parameter. And the onMenuClick is only passed the 'MenuItem'

Thank you for any direction that can be provided

[Sceenshot of my ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyqgF.jpg)

It appears I might be going about implementing the popoup menu the wrong way?

Comment: Ask the `Adapter` to do it for you ... ?

Comment: Good effort. But all the Adapter is giving me is the data it last read i.e. The bottom (or top) item in the Listview (depending on which way I last scrolled). Thank you for the comment

Comment: I can't believe that this pretty straighforward requirement isn't easy or obvious - popup menus from ListView Items must surely be commonplace and most apps are going to want to do something with the ListItem data....
... However I can solve the problem by passing the database table key as a tag in the button view. Bit of a dirty hack and it means I have to read the database again so it's not ideal. Oh well at least I can get over the hurde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness, here's my solution.

I never did find a way of accessing the `ListItem` data directly.

Instead, in the `CursorAdapter` `bindView` I added a tag to the `ListView` `button`, holding the `ListItem` position, and the database item key value.

Then on the button click handler I read the tag and save the key value and `(Cursor) mListview.getAdapter().getItem(mSelectedBikePosition)` in member variables to be used in the `onMenuItemClick` handler.